# MVC - AJAX Post - Open Partial View in Dialog Box

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my Bootstrap Dialog Box, I have a AJAX form :-

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Method", "Settings", FormMethod.Post, null))
 {
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row form-horizontal" id="fieldsList">
      ....
   <button type="submit" class="btn">Back</button>
 }



[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Method(FormCollection form)
        {
            ....
            return PartialView("pagePartial",model);            
        }
```

When I hit the submit Button, the Dialog box closes & i see a new page.

How to open the `PartialView` in Dialog itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Method", "Settings", new AjaxOption{httpMethod="post", onSuccess="onSuccess"}))
 {
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row form-horizontal" id="fieldsList">
      ....
   <button type="submit" class="btn">Back</button>
 }


 <script>
   function onSuccess(result){
     //Your code
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: I tried ur code, it is still opening as a new page.

Comment: Convert `public ActionResult Method(FormCollection form)` to `PartialViewResult ` after that try.

Comment: Convert `public ActionResult Method(FormCollection form)` to `public PartialViewResult Method(FormCollection form)` after that try.

Comment: Still No Luck...Complete page refreshes..!